# Initializing a Three Dimensional Vector in a C++ Class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization, init

Using the following code I would like to move a multidimensional vector in various directions. Unfortunately right after initializing I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Direction: Values from 0 to 2 for x,y and z movement

Steps: Only -1 and 1 (Back, Forward)

Container: Multidimensional Vector

```
if (verMove(direction, steps)==true) {

std::vector<int> val(4,0);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> val2(4,val); /// ERROR
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> newContainer(4,val2);

// Move in X Direction
for (int a=0; a<4; a++) {
    for (int b=0; b<4; b++) {
        for (int c=0; c<4; c++) {

            int d;

            if (steps<0)
                d=3;
            else
                d=0;

            switch (direction) {
                case 0:
                    if (c==d)
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = 0;
                    else if (steps>0)
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = this->container[a][b][c-1];
                    else
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = this->container[a][b][c+1];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (b==d)
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = 0;
                    else if (steps>0)
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = this->container[a][b-1][c];
                    else
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = this->container[a][b+1][c];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (a==d)
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = 0;
                    else if (steps>0)
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = this->container[a-1][b][c];
                    else
                        newContainer[a][b][c] = this->container[a+1][b][c];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

    replaceContainer(newContainer);

} else {

    return;

}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure you are building with `-std=c++11` or its equivalent for your compiler? `>>` as two template delimiters wasn't allowed before c++11 and you would have to put a space like this `std::vector<std::vector<int> > val2(4,val);`.

Comment: yes it is a standard c++11 compiler

Comment: Try to comment out rest of the code in `if`'s and check out if there sill is error. Then try to narrow by progressing with uncommenting chunks of code until error is back. Then you know where it is.

Comment: This code still compiles for me, so it must be compiler-specific error (old implmenetation or something) or there must be error in other place.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help anyway :) Will dig a littele deeper ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code (with vectors) works. [Live example](http://ideone.com/zl83vo). Try to add space betwen two `>` signs (`>>`) and check if it helps.

Another way to initialize vector is using std::initializer_list like this:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> myVec = 
    { 
        { 
            { 0, 1 }, 
            { 2, 3} 
        }, 
        { 
            { 4, 5 }, 
            { 6, 7 } 
        } 
    };
```

[Live example #2](http://ideone.com/WLfyc5)

Comment: I have added spaces like you suggested, but the error remains unchanged.

Comment: @PhilippBraun - what compiler do you use?

Comment: I am using XCode I think it is gcc. And I am pretty sure that it is NOT a compiler error. Probably some reallocation error or so.

Comment: Thanks for the help I think I need to search at an other place for the error.

Comment: Check if you do not want to acces out-of-bounds index (like when you have 4x4x4 array, check if you do not acces elements with indices less then zero or bigger then 3.